# Replace data entry errors with the most common value - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame which contains some data entry errors.

I wish to replace these outlier values per group with the most common value per group.

My data looks as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(CODE = c("J1745","J1745","J1745","J1745","J1100","J1100","J1100","J1100","J1100","J1100"),NDC = c(1234,1234,1234,1234,5678,5678,5678,5678,5678,5678),DOSAGE = c("10ML","10 ML","10 ML","10 ML","5 ML","5 ML","5 ML","5 ML","50 ML","5 ML"),DESC = c("TEXT1","TEXT 1","TEXT 1","TEXT 1","TEXT 2","TEXT 2","TEXT 2","TEXT 2","TEXT 10","TEXT 2"))
```

[image]

As you can see my `DOSAGE` and `DESC` columns contain some inconsistencies and I would like to replace them with the most common value within each group.

My desired output looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to replace with the most common value? it is not a good practice. I think it would be better to try to use some regular expression to try to replace them with their correct value, and not just imputing by the most frequent category.

Comment: Can you please post your input and output examples as text (code blocks) rather than screenshots? It's more accessible ...

Comment: You accepted @RonakShah's  answer, but see my comment there for why this might not be what you want.. Can you please clarify what you mean by/how you would define "outlier values" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/3962914) to get the most common value.

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Apply this function by group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(CODE, NDC) %>% mutate(across(c(DOSAGE, DESC), Mode)) %>% ungroup

#    CODE    NDC DOSAGE DESC  
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 J1745  1234 10 ML  TEXT 1
# 2 J1745  1234 10 ML  TEXT 1
# 3 J1745  1234 10 ML  TEXT 1
# 4 J1745  1234 10 ML  TEXT 1
# 5 J1100  5678 5 ML   TEXT 2
# 6 J1100  5678 5 ML   TEXT 2
# 7 J1100  5678 5 ML   TEXT 2
# 8 J1100  5678 5 ML   TEXT 2
# 9 J1100  5678 5 ML   TEXT 2
#10 J1100  5678 5 ML   TEXT 2
```

Comment: This does match the desired output, but it doesn't do what the OP said they wanted. This replaces **all** of the values in a group with the mode.  The OP said they wanted to replace "outlier values" (not clearly defined) with the mode.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment that this is potentially dangerous.

The code below replaces elements that have <= a specified number of occurrences with the most common value.  I use base-R machinery within the replacement function because that's what I know how to do.

```r
repl_common <- function(x,n=1) {
    tt <- tapply(x,x,length)          ## count number of instances
    m <- names(tt)[which.max(tt)]     ## find mode
    x[tt[as.character(x)]<=n] <- m    ## replace
    return(x)
}
## apply by group across specified columns
df %>% group_by(CODE) %>% mutate(across(c(DOSAGE,DESC), repl_common))
```

Comment: Replacing the first line of the function with a call to `tabulate()` might be slightly cleaner.